# Google Chrome in Incognito Mode still logging visits history

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I am using Incognito Mode and today I have noticed that when I frequently visit some site in that mode browser logs it and even on not incognito mode it autofills in address bar making Incognito mode useless in my case.

Another fun thing is that the item is not in History so I can't manually remove it.

Couldn't find anything in Settings. Why is this happening?

BTW, instant search is disabled in my case.

Using the latest version to date.

**Extensions installed**

- List item
- Send to Google Docs
- Google Translate
- Eye Dropper
- Delicious
- Readabiliy
- Pagespeed

Comment: are you sure it's the browser and not some log on the site that does this? it could work of your IP address or something similar

Comment: how would site make browser to save it's address? (no bookmark either)

Comment: I mean is it possible for the *site* to log your IP address and make suggestions. It's hard to give a specific answer without knowing what site(s) you're referring to.

Comment: but how can browser get those suggestions when I type in the address bar the first characters like the site is theinsider.com

Comment: so if I start typing "theins" how the TheInsider.com would suggest me itself. It's a browser issue or Google search issue..weird

Comment: well if you've ever visited theinsider *outside* of incognito mode, it's saved in your browsing history. Chrome will make recommendations based on what you've browsed to before, or to popular searches.

Comment: right! but I have never visited outside Incognito Mode!

Comment: @casey_miller Please edit your question to include **all** extensions you have installed. "History related" is vague.

Comment: Try clearing all your web history and then start Chrome in incognito mode and see if it still happens.

Comment: @BJ292 I tried really.

Comment: I'm much sure that this is due to Google search. As I type a site which I had never open in my browser and yeah its still showing the result for that.

Comment: @avirk it's even worse! because I am using bit.ly and it really preserves URL's. I mean that normally browser wouldn't guess bit.ly's hash in any way. So in this case incognito is not really incognito

Comment: Report your issues here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: This isen't a fix, but have you tried The SRWare Iron fork of Chrome? It is the same, a Chromium, and has much better privacy.

Comment: When I start to type in the omnibox and get a URL I don't have in my history I use Shift+Delete and it removes it from the suggestions. So far it hasn't come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear you are running into the intended feature of the omnibox, it will give you auto-suggestions pulled from the internet as you type.

If you start typing 'superu' it may bring up superuser.com even if you have never been here before. this is not instant search as you mention you do not have enabled, instant search is an extension of this where it will actually load the best result, aka your feeling lucky, as you type. with instant search enabled it would already be loading superuser.com if you started typing it and it was the best result based on google magic.

> Turning off Auto-Suggestions
>
> 1. Clear your browsing history
> 2. Click the Tools menu
> 3. Select Options
> 4. Click the Under the Hood tab and find the ''Privacy section
> 5. Deselect the 'Use a suggestion service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar' checkbox.
> 6. Click Close.

referance:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/0DR-pLIVI5g/XuqF5qasts8J

Comment: I used the short URL's (bit.ly) how would it auto suggest? So it still tracks!. I marked this as Answered though.

Answer (score 1):

The Incognito window in Google Chrome is meant to allow you to browse without storing your history or cookies that will connect your browser to your searches. If your primary problem is the auto-completion/auto-filling of addresses, just clear your history.

Comment: That is really stupid. The whole intention of incognito is so you don't have to do that.